# How to install fGarch package

Tags: r, garch

How do I install the `fGarch` package for R?  When I run `install.packages('fGarch')`, it returns `package ‘fGarch’ is available as a source package but not as a binary`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use software.

Comment: try `install.packages("fGarch", type = "source")` - there are no binaries (for Windows, at least), but if you have a local FORTRAN compiler you're in business.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rstudio, it is farily easy to install packages, just go to `Tools` on navigation bar, click on `Install Packages...`.

You can do it in two ways:

1. Download the Cran packages from: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/index.html, and choose "Install from Package Archive File"
2. Choose "Install from Repository", and type in fGarch, it will search,download, and install it for you automatically.

Comment: Why do you assume the OP uses RStudio?

Comment: Well I believe Rstudio is one of the most popular interface tools for R scripting?